# Replacing single backslashes with double backslashes in php

Tags: php, backslash

I came across a strange problem in my PHP programming. While using the `backtrace` function to get the last file the PHP compiler was working with. It would give it to me the path using backslashes. I wanted to store this string in the database, but MySQL would remove them; I'm assuming it was thinking I wanted to escape them.

So `C:\Path\To\Filename.php` would end up `C:PathToFileName.php` in the database. When I posted this question to Google, I found many others with the same problem but in many different situations. People always suggested something like:

```
$str = '\dada\dadda';
var_dump(str_replace('\', '\\', $str));
```

The problems with this is, even if you put it into a loop of some kind, is that you just keep replacing the first `\` with `\\`. So it starts off like `\` then `\\\` then `\\\\\` then `\\\\\\\` then `\\\\\\\\\` etc... Until it fills the memory buffer with this huge string.

My solution to this problem, if anyone else has it is:

```
//$file = C:\Path\To\Filename.php

//Need to use \\ so it ends up being \
$fileArray = explode("\\", $file);

//take the first one off the array
$file = array_shift($fileArray);

//go thru the rest of the array and add \\\\ then the next folder
foreach($fileArray as $folder){
    $file .= "\\\\" . $folder;
}

echo $file
//This will give you C:\\Path\\To\\Filename.php
```

So when it's stored in the database, it will appear to be `C:\Path\To\Filename.php`.

If anyone else has a better solution to this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "double escape" them inside `preg_replace` parameters (once for the string, once for the regex engine):

```
$mystring = 'c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts';
$escaped = preg_replace('/\\\\/','\\\\\\\\',$mystring);

echo "New string is:  $escaped\n";
```

Or only once if you use `str_replace`:

```
 $newstring = str_replace('\\','\\\\',$mystring);

 echo "str_replace : $newstring\n";
?>
```

Comment: Clearly, using `preg_replace` isn't the good function, `str_replace` is more appropriate to deal with literal strings. It's also possible with `strtr`.

Comment: How do I get preg_replace for me, just change where \\ is, to another value? Because the code above is changing as far as there is only one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_real_escape_string('C:\Path\To\Filename.php');
```

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() for 5.5.0+ This is defintely the right way to go since it's a mysql situation.  However, added answer to general backslash escape below since it's useful to know.

Comment: The first time I tired mysqli_real_escape_string it didn't work, but I just tested it out again and it seemed to work. Would've saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` doesn't escape only backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex capture group ():

```
echo preg_replace('/([\\\])/', '${1}${1}', "\b is a metasequence");
// 3 backslahses

// outputs: \\b is a metasequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid but works for me.

```
$BS='\\\';
```

(You put a double backslash in the $BS, but actually you get one backslash only.

```
$FullName = "C:".$BS.$BS."Path".$BS."To".$BS."FileName.php";
```

You should get the $FullName "C:\\Path\To\Filename.php"