# Replacing backslashes with two blackslashes

Tags: php, regex, replace

Does anyone know how I can replace backslashes with two backslashes? Using Perl, I'd do:

```perl
$str = "C:\\Pub";      # Stores C:\Pub
$str =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;  
print $str;            # Outputs C:\\Pub
```

Can I do something like that in PHP? I tried `preg_replace()` function but it didn't worked!

Comment: Did you look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983782/replacing-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes-in-php ? Also, please show what you tried in PHP.

Comment: `C:\\Pub` is the expected output? There is no `g` modifier in PHP and there needs to be an leading and trailing delimiter.

Comment: thank you AntonH, your tip fixed my problem!