# PHP - How to replace single backslashes that precede numbers with double backslashes

Tags: php, replace, backslash

Unlike for characters, replacing single backslashes with double backslashes is not working for numbers. Is there a way to accomplish this in PHP?.

```
$attributes = "red\blue\green";
echo "<br>".str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $attributes);
//Output: red\\blue\\green
echo "<br>".preg_replace("/\\\\/", "\\\\\\\\", $attributes);
//Output: red\\blue\\green

// Unlike for characters, it doesn't work for numbers
$attributes = "25\30\35\40\45";
echo "<br>".str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $attributes);
//Output: 25 %
echo "<br>".preg_replace("/\\\\/", "\\\\\\\\", $attributes);
//Output: 25 %
```

Comment: Replace `"` with `'`. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing single backslashes with double backslashes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983782/replacing-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes-in-php)

Comment: hey, just following up to see if my answer helped? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the double quotes - changing to single quotes, like so:

```
$attributes = '25\30\35\40\45';
echo "<br>".str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $attributes);
```

works, the `\` inside a double quote was parsing the string as an [octal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) - single quotes will parse what's given as a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**

```
$attributes = "red\blue\green";
$newstring = preg_replace('/\\\\/','\\\\\\\\',$attributes);

echo  $newstring;
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hHlbo)**

and use With **str_replace**

```
$attributes = '25\30\35\40\45';
$newstring = str_replace('\\','\\\\',$mystring);

echo $newstring;
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/69oqt)**