# Use preg_replace() to add two backslashes before each match

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backslash

I have code below, what I need to change to get result `mercedes\\-benz` instead of `mercedes\-benz`

```
$value = 'mercedes-benz';
$pattern = '/(\+|-|\/|&&|\|\||!|\(|\)|\{|}|\[|]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|:|\\\)/';
$replace = '\\\\${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
```

Comment: @lukas.j it is works, why we need to use so much `\` symbols?

Comment: This title is too vague to be searchable.  Why capture the entire match? Why not condense your pattern using a character class?

Comment: I think changing the delimiter to a backtick and using `([-+!()[\]{}^"~/*?:\\]|&{2}|\|{2})` might be cleaner... what are you converting this for, mysql regex?

Comment: Related: [Replacing single backslashes with double backslashes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15983782/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of "leaning toothpick syndrome" - backslash is such a commonly used escape character that it frequently requires escaping multiple times. Let's have a look at your case:

- Required output (presumably because of some other escaping context): `\\`
- Escape each `\` with an additional `\` for use in the PCRE regex engine: `\\\\`
- Escape each `\` *there* for use in a PHP string: `\\\\\\\\`

```
$value = 'mercedes-benz';
$pattern = '/(\+|-|\/|&&|\|\||!|\(|\)|\{|}|\[|]|\^|"|~|\*|\?|:|\\\)/';
$replace = '\\\\\\\\${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
```

As [mickmackusa points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71033788/157957), you can get away with *six* rather than *eight* backslashes in some cases, such as a replacement of `'\\\\\\'`; this works because the regex engine sees `\\\`, which is an escaped backslash (`\\`) followed by a single backslash (`\`) that can't be escaping anything because it's the end of the string. Simply doubling for each "layer" of escaping is probably safer than learning when this short-cut is and isn't valid, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure that I've 100% translated your original attempt, but this works for your lone sample input.

The pattern uses a character class and curly braced quantifiers to improve readability and brevity.  Using `\K` eliminates the need for the reference in the replacement string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rct7Z))

```
$value = 'mercedes-benz';
$pattern = '`&{2}|\|{2}|[-+/!(){}[\]^"~*?:\\\]\K`';
$replace = '\\\\\\';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
```

Ultimately, the trick was to keep adding backslashes to the replacement to get them to show up.

Comment: This passes a sequence of _three_ backticks to the regex engine, which happens to work in this case because the third one can't mean anything other than itself; for the general case, though, you need to pass _four_ there, which means having _eight_ in the PHP string.

Comment: I am using backslashes, not backticks. When I can use a working solution that has less characters than a longer working solution, I usually choose the shorter one unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: Sorry, "backticks" was just a typo (I would have typed a literal backslash, but Markdown is terrible). I'm suggesting that the good reason not to use this shortened version is that it will break if the replacement string is tweaked in any way that changes the meaning of the third backslash.